# Identify soundtrack of this video about Fallout 4

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

I would like to identify the soundtrack of this video about fallout 4: [Гигантская саранча была подстрелена в 1937 году в Бостоне. Гайд по игре Фоллаут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fg9o7pJU8yo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The song is a cover of *Somewhere over the Rainbow* by the Hawaiian singer and ukulele player [Israel "IZ" Kamakawiwoʻole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1bFr2SWP1I) in 1990.

The song is originaly from 1939, and featured in the movie [*The Wizard of Oz*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSZxmZmBfnU).